# Responsive Nav Menu Won't Display After Expanding Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When my window hits 670px, the nav menu gets a css class display:none;. Then a drop down icon appears. The drop down icon has a slideToggle that displays the ul li navigation menu and that works. However, once the window expands again, the ul li is nowhere to be found. If anyone could help out then than would be amazing.

Here's the code.

```
<style>
body{
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
}
.menu-trigger img{display: none;}
.header_background{
    background-image: url('backgrounddd.jpg');
    position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.clearfixone{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;

}
.divone{
    max-width: 995px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;


}
#logo{
    height:90px;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.nav-menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right:2px solid #bfcec7;
    line-height: 30px;
}
li#middle{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
div.nav-expanded{
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width:990px) {
    .nav-menu ul{
        padding:0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .nav-menu ul li{
    background-color:rgba(0, 0,0, 0.7);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right:none;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: none;


}
.menu-trigger img{
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display:block;

}
.nav-menu ul{
    display: none;

}
div.nav-expanded{
    display: block;
}

}

</style>
<div class="clearfixone">
          <div class="divone">
          <span class="menu-trigger"><img class="dropdown"src="http://i.imgur.com/Y9huMMG.png"></span>
<div class="nav-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
            <li class="extra"><a href="#">Services Offered</a></li>
                <li class="extra"><a href="#">Learn More </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li id="middle"><a href="#">Request a Quote</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
    </div></div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {

        jQuery(".nav-menu, ul").slideToggle(400, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', 'content');
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a media-query with a min-width at the same screen width, to re-apply the display: block style back onto the nav menu.

```
@media screen and (min-width:990px){
    .nav-menu ul { display: block !important; }
}

@media screen and (max-width:990px) { 
    .nav-menu ul { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: If you do inspect the HTML and find the hidden element, does it have inline styles applied to it?

Comment: By the way, hopefully you didn't just cut and paste my code from above, because I just noticed I misspelled "screen".

Comment: I'm guessing that the slideToggle that shows/hides your element is placing an inline style of "display: none" after it slides up. Inline styles will override regular CSS. So you may have to put an "!important" flag on your display: block to make sure it takes precedent over the inline display: none.